# Yii jui date picker format

Tags: yii2

I am using the following code in my _form file for yii\jui\DatePicker, on date selection it is showing the date format properly. In gridview the data rendered is OK.

But when I open the record for update, the format shown is yyyy-mm-dd, I want to show the same as dd-mm-yyyy

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'birth_date')->widget(DatePicker::className(),


                    [
                        'language' => 'en',
                        'clientOptions' =>[
                        'dateFormat' => 'd-m-yy',
                        'language' => 'US',
                        'country' => 'IN',
                        'showAnim'=>'fold',
                        'yearRange' => 'c-25:c+0',
                        'changeMonth'=> true,
                        'changeYear'=> true,
                        'autoSize'=>true,
                        'showOn'=> "button",
                         //'buttonImage'=> "images/calendar.gif",
                        'htmlOptions'=>[
                        'style'=>'width:80px;',
                        'font-weight'=>'x-small',
                        ],]]) ?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format date in your controller, then render the view. In controller:

```
$model->birth_date=Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->birth_date, "dd-mm-yyyy");
```

Take a look at Yii2's official `formatter` guide [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-formatter.html).

Comment: Works perfect. I have simply added the code in controller with modification `dd-M-yyyy`.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: HI @Ali : Is it possible to show 'Time' options in this plugin.? As, I was using 'Kartik DateTime Picker'. It was working fine. But, client want to use time in date picker. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You can Generalize the date format

```
class Setup {
    const DATE_FORMAT = 'php:Y-m-d';
    const DATETIME_FORMAT = 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s';
    const TIME_FORMAT = 'php:H:i:s';

    public static function convert($dateStr, $type='date', $format = null) {
        if ($type === 'datetime') {
              $fmt = ($format == null) ? self::DATETIME_FORMAT : $format;
        }
        elseif ($type === 'time') {
              $fmt = ($format == null) ? self::TIME_FORMAT : $format;
        }
        else {
              $fmt = ($format == null) ? self::DATE_FORMAT : $format;
        }
        return \Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($dateStr, $fmt);
    }
}
```

Then anywhere else (like controller/model) you can access this function to convert any input date/time string for saving to database.

```
$model->birth_date = Setup::convert($model->dateAttr);
$model->birth_date = Setup::convert($model->datetimeAttr, 'datetime');
```